# Kube-Flannel cant get CIDR although PodCIDR available on node

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, flannel

currently I am setting up Kubernetes on a 1 Master 2 Node enviorement.

I succesfully initialized the Master and added the nodes to the Cluster

[kubectl get nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4lXG.png)

When I joined the Nodes to the cluster, the kube-proxy pod started succesfully, but the kube-flannel pod gets an error and runs into a CrashLoopBackOff.

***flannel-pod.log:***

```
I0613 09:03:36.820387       1 main.go:475] Determining IP address of default interface,
I0613 09:03:36.821180       1 main.go:488] Using interface with name ens160 and address 172.17.11.2,
I0613 09:03:36.821233       1 main.go:505] Defaulting external address to interface address (172.17.11.2),
I0613 09:03:37.015163       1 kube.go:131] Waiting 10m0s for node controller to sync,
I0613 09:03:37.015436       1 kube.go:294] Starting kube subnet manager,
I0613 09:03:38.015675       1 kube.go:138] Node controller sync successful,
I0613 09:03:38.015767       1 main.go:235] Created subnet manager: Kubernetes Subnet Manager - caasfaasslave1.XXXXXX.local,
I0613 09:03:38.015828       1 main.go:238] Installing signal handlers,
I0613 09:03:38.016109       1 main.go:353] Found network config - Backend type: vxlan,
I0613 09:03:38.016281       1 vxlan.go:120] VXLAN config: VNI=1 Port=0 GBP=false DirectRouting=false,
E0613 09:03:38.016872       1 main.go:280] Error registering network: failed to acquire lease: node "caasfaasslave1.XXXXXX.local" pod cidr not assigned,
I0613 09:03:38.016966       1 main.go:333] Stopping shutdownHandler...,
```

On the Node, I can verify that the PodCDIR is available:

```
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.podCIDR}'
172.17.12.0/24
```

On the Masters kube-controller-manager, the pod cidr is also there

```
[root@caasfaasmaster manifests]# cat kube-controller-manager.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-controller-manager
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-controller-manager
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    - --leader-elect=true
    - --controllers=*,bootstrapsigner,tokencleaner
    - --cluster-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key
    - --address=127.0.0.1
    - --use-service-account-credentials=true
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
    - --cluster-signing-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --allocate-node-cidrs=true
    - --cluster-cidr=172.17.12.0/24
    - --node-cidr-mask-size=24
    env:
    - name: http_proxy
      value: http://ntlmproxy.XXXXXX.local:3154
    - name: https_proxy
      value: http://ntlmproxy.XXXXXX.local:3154
    - name: no_proxy
      value: .XXXXX.local,172.17.11.0/24,172.17.12.0/24
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager-amd64:v1.10.4
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10252
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-controller-manager
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
      name: kubeconfig
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/pki
      name: ca-certs-etc-pki
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs-etc-pki
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: kubeconfig
status: {}
```

XXXXX for anonymization

I initialized the master with the following kubeadm comman (which also went through without any errors)

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=172.17.12.0/24 --service- 
cidr=172.17.11.129/25 --service-dns-domain=dcs.XXXXX.local
```

Does anyone know what could cause my issues and how to fix them?

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                  READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE
kube-system   etcd-caasfaasmaster.XXXXXX.local                      1/1       Running            0          16h       172.17.11.1   caasfaasmaster.XXXXXX.local
kube-system   kube-apiserver-caasfaasmaster.XXXXXX.local            1/1       Running            1          16h       172.17.11.1   caasfaasmaster.XXXXXX.local
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-caasfaasmaster.XXXXXX.local   1/1       Running            0          16h       172.17.11.1   caasfaasmaster.XXXXXX.local
kube-system   kube-dns-75c5968bf9-qfh96                             3/3       Running            0          16h       172.17.12.2   caasfaasmaster.XXXXXX.local
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-4b6kf                                 0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   205        16h       172.17.11.2   caasfaasslave1.XXXXXX.local
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-j2fz6                                 0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   191        16h       172.17.11.3   caasfassslave2.XXXXXX.local
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-qjd89                                 1/1       Running            0          16h       172.17.11.1   caasfaasmaster.XXXXXX.local
kube-system   kube-proxy-h4z54                                      1/1       Running            0          16h       172.17.11.3   caasfassslave2.XXXXXX.local
kube-system   kube-proxy-sjwl2                                      1/1       Running            0          16h       172.17.11.2   caasfaasslave1.XXXXXX.local
kube-system   kube-proxy-zc5xh                                      1/1       Running            0          16h       172.17.11.1   caasfaasmaster.XXXXXX.local
kube-system   kube-scheduler-caasfaasmaster.XXXXXX.local            1/1       Running            0          16h       172.17.11.1   caasfaasmaster.XXXXXX.local
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Flannel [documentation](https://coreos.com/flannel/docs/latest/flannel-config.html):

> At the bare minimum, you must tell flannel an IP range (subnet) that
>   it should use for the overlay. Here is an example of the minimum
>   flannel configuration:
>
> ```
> { "Network": "10.1.0.0/16" }
> ```

Therefore, you need to specify a network for pods with a minimum size of `/16`, and it should not be a part of your existing network because Flannel uses encapsulation to connect pods on different nodes to one overlay network.

Here is the part of documentation which describes it:

> With Docker, each container is assigned an IP address that can be used
>   to communicate with other containers on the same host. For
>   communicating over a network, containers are tied to the IP addresses
>   of the host machines and must rely on port-mapping to reach the
>   desired container. This makes it difficult for applications running
>   inside containers to advertise their external IP and port as that
>   information is not available to them.
>
> flannel solves the problem by giving each container an IP that can be
>   used for container-to-container communication. It uses packet
>   encapsulation to create a virtual overlay network that spans the whole
>   cluster. More specifically, **flannel gives each host an IP subnet
>   (/24 by default)** from which the Docker daemon is able to allocate
>   IPs to the individual containers.

In other words, you should recreate your cluster with settings like these:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.17.0.0/16 --service-cidr=10.18.0.0/24 --service-dns-domain=dcs.XXXXX.local
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that out too. Basically, I had to init my master with the configuration File. In the File I specified the Range of the Node subnet to /25. If you want to do this be carefull, since the config option is alpha you can easily run into this github issue. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/724

Bottom Line: Do not change the default parameters or it will jump right in your face.

Comment: If you do not wish to recreate (init) the whole cluster again, patch all nodes as suggested in the below reply.

Answer (score 16):

Failed to acquire lease simply means, the pod didn't get the podCIDR. Happened with me as well although the manifest on master-node says podCIDR true but still it wasn't working and funnel going in crashbackloop.
This is what i did to fix it.

From the master-node, first find out your funnel CIDR

```
sudo cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml | grep -i cluster-cidr
```

Output:

```
- --cluster-cidr=172.168.10.0/24
```

Then run the following from the master node:

```
kubectl patch node slave-node-1 -p '{"spec":{"podCIDR":"172.168.10.0/24"}}'
```

where, 
slave-node-1 is your node where acquire lease is failing
podCIDR is the cidr that you found in previous command

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had already defined my cluster network cidr during initialisation so the accepted answer wasn't going to work for me. I applied this patch and my flannel pods stood up not long after. Thanks.

Comment: Since I have created my cluster using ```sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=172.31.0.0/24```, flannel pods were failing on all nodes.  I have patched all nodes ( command need to be run on master ) ```kubectl patch node <node-N> -p '{"spec":{"podCIDR":"172.31.10.0/24"}}' ``` and deleted Creashed pods to get flannel pods back in Running state.